# Click event doesn't bubble up

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my page.html I have a div like this:

```
<div class="news-text" (click)="expandContent($event)" tappable>
    <h1 class="news-title">{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p class="news-content">{{ post.content }}</span></p>
    <p class="news-date">{{ post.date }}</p>
</div>
```

in my page.ts I have:

```
expandContent(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    //bla bla
}
```

The problem is that the output is always the clicked child of the div.

For example, if I click the paragraph with class 'news-date' the event target is 'p.news-date' and my function doesn't trigger in the div specified.

How can I trigger my event function in the div specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a template variable

```
<div class="news-text" #div (click)="expandContent($event, div)" tappable>
```

If you only want to pass the element, you can also omit `$event,`